# Как привязать множество моделей к одной ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

Есть, например,такие классы:

```
class A(models.Model):
 id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
 mtm = models.ManyToManyField(B, C, D)

class B(models.Model):
 id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
class C(models.Model):
 id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
class D(models.Model):
 id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
```

Я знаю, что реализация поля класса А неправильная, сделал так что бы было понятнее. Нужно что бы модель А имела связь ManyToMany с моделями В,С,D. Как это можно сделать? Есть ли специальное поле?

Answer (score 0):

Модели B, C и D можно [наследовать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) от общего корня

```
class Base(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)

class A(models.Model):
    mtm = models.ManyToManyField(Base)

class B(Base):
    pass

class C(Base):
    pass

class D(Base):
    pass
```